# How to implement IEnumerator in MVC4 application with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, ienumerator

I am trying to return two models in one view in my MVC4 project by following [this tutorial](http://francorobles.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/returning-multiple-models-in-1-view-in-asp-net-mvc3/). I have one Model named Product that looks like this:

```
public class Product : IEnumerable<ShoppingCartViewModel>, 
                           IList<ShoppingCartViewModel>
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        (...)
    }
```

And a ViewModel with a list of ShoppingCarts (List) that looks like this:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel : IEnumerable<Product>, IList<Product>
    {
        public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
        public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

I have one "wrapper model" that does the following:

```
public class ProductAndCartWrapperModel
    {
        public Product product;
        public ShoppingCartViewModel shoppingCart;

        public ProductAndCartWrapperModel()
        {
            product = new Product();
            shoppingCart = new ShoppingCartViewModel();
        }
}
```

Then I try to simply display the view with the two different models in this way

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<projectname.ProductAndCartWrapperModel>" %>
(...)
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <% foreach (projectname.Models.Product p in
                                     ViewData.Model.product) { %>
        <div>
            <div id="ProductName"><%: p.Name %></div>
            <div id="ProductPrice"><%: p.Price %></div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <% foreach (projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel sc in 
                   ViewData.Model.shoppingCart) { %>
        <div>
            <div id="Div1"><%: sc.CartItems %></div>
            <div id="Div2"><%: sc.CartTotal %></div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Unfortunately, when trying to build I get one error

```
Cannot convert type 'projectname.Models.Product' to
'projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel'
```

followed by a list of errors that look like this for both the models:

```
does not implement interface member 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel>.
 GetEn umerator()'. 'projectname.Models.Product.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement  
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel>.
 GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel>'.
```

I have the feeling I am quite close to displaying both of the models on one page, but I do not know how to implement the IEnumerator and get the types to match. I tried to add one like this:

```
public IEnumerator<Object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

but that was to no avail.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain how to correctly implement the interface members and get the solution to build (if possible).

Comment: Why does the `Product` implement an `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartViewModel>`? If you need to enumerate *over* something in your view, just setup your view model to have an `IEnumerable<T>` (of the object you want to enumerate over). Your view models seem unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I did that because the tutorial is doing that too. But okay, I can only enumerate over product? And how do I make this IEnumerable<Product> in my viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Product` inherits from `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartViewModel>`, it means that iterating over `Product` will give `ShoppingCartViewModel` elements.

```
<% foreach (Product p in ViewData.Model.product) { %>
```

should be :

```
<% foreach (ShoppingCartViewModel p in ViewData.Model.product) { %>
```

But your design here is quite weird, maybe are you overdoing it ?

Comment: Wow! Doing this in combination with bump's comment (removing IList implementation) got rid of a whole load of errors. The only 4 errors I get now are similar to this one:

Error 4 'projectname.Models.Product' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<projectname.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel>.GetEnumerator()'                                   

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This is because you have to define how enumeration will occure when inheriting from `IEnumerable`. If you don't need to implement specific behavior for `GetEnumerator`, you can just use  `List<ShoppingCartViewM‌odel>`  instead of `IEnumerable<ShoppingCartViewM‌odel>`

Comment: Okay removing the IEnumerable's did indeed make the solution build, but when I go to the page with the two models I get the following error: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'projectname.Models.Product' because 'projectname.Models.Product' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'. So I think I need to define one and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You still need an implementation of `GetEnumerator` to use `foreach`, that's why i told you to use `List` instead of `IEnumerable`, as it suits your need : `public class Product : List<ShoppingCartViewModel>`. Removing both won't allow you to iterate over your collection.

Comment: Thanks you are a genius. The solution is building and the page is displaying without errors. Unfortunately the information is not yet displayed but that must be solve-able. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay I got it to work! What I wanted to do was display two models on one view. In the end I added a ViewModel class that had a List<Product> productItems and List<Cart> cartItems. That way I could combine the two controllers of the two views I wanted to display in one. Now my foreach loop in the combined view could reach the Products and the Carts by using Model.productItems and Model.cartItems.